# Обновление данных с БД в реальном времени

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Например есть бд и я хочу чтобы в какой-то div выводилась информация о количестве строк в реальном времени. Чтобы не долбить запросами каждых n секунд.
Посоветуйте, может есть готовые примеры.

Comment: Websocket или что-то в таком роде

Comment: Вам поможет Websocket или что-то в таком роде.

Comment: А более конкретнее?) Может есть  уже примеры готовые?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй веб-сокеты. Вот библиотека на php: https://github.com/walkor/Workerman
И от этого же автора есть более удобная обертка над workerman с примером онлайн чата:
https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io

А в js можешь использовать https://socket.io/

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже нашел решение.